# Pick values from selectedItems in ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Im getting the selected rows in the ng-grid default array (selectedItems).

I was wondering if anyone knows how to get specific values and not the whole row of values?

For example, I have the following columns:

Product | Value | Quantity | Information | ID | Weight | Stock

I want my result to have only the name and ID... Is this possible?
The selectedItems array shows every column and value of the selected item.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the array index to get to the data.

For example `selectedItems[0].Value` gives the `Value` of the first item. I hope that is what you meant.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I got a bit confused: selectedItems is a JSON result with nested elements...
Using selectedItems[0].Value doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.$watch('gridOptions.selectedItems', function (selectedRows, oldSelection) {
  $scope.result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
    $scope.result.push({
      id: selectedRows[i].id,
      value: selectedRows[i].value
    });
  }
});
```

`$scope.result` will be an array of objects that contain only the ID and Value for each of the selected rows in your grid

Comment: Im getting "Cannot read property 'selectedItems' of undefined"... should I add the for condition inside a watch?

Comment: yep...I will edit my answer to include it within a watch

Comment: Thanks Kabb, I was able to do it with a ForEach statement.
I will be pasting my solution soon